# Using Integer Value from Realm Query

Tags: objective-c, realm

I'm learning to use Realm and I have a question based on the sample code provided by their website. How do I query and then use a integer specific value that was saved in my realm. Here is a summary of my code:

```
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property NSInteger age;
@property NSInteger id;
@end

@implementation Dog

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
return @"id";
}

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {

dogSelected = arc4random_uniform(10);

Dog *mydog = [[Dog alloc] init];
mydog.age = 10;
mydog.id = dogSelected;

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[Dog createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:mydog];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];


dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("background", 0), ^{RLMResults<Dog *> *r = [Dog objectsWhere:@"id == %d",dogSelected];
```

The RLMResults are then logged as:

```
    age = 10;
    id = 0;
```

What I want to do is isolate the integer 10 that I just queired and set it to a new "ageQueried" integer that I can later use in a new method. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to use the found dog's age in a subsequent query?

Comment: I want to be able to set the found dog's age to a new NSInteger to use in a new method. In this case its an integer of 10. But I don't know how to get just that value from the query. For example, I want to query just the age, and then increment it by one if it fits my criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm on the right path here, but accessing the value of the `Dog`'s age from those results should simply be a matter of:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    RLMResults<Dog *> *r = [Dog objectsWhere:@"id == %d",dogSelected];
    Dog *dog = r.firstObject; //Get the first Dog object from the RLMResults set
    NSInteger ageQueried = dog.age;
});
```

*(Sidenote: It's probably better to use `dispatch_get_global_queue()` here as explicitly creating new queues requires you to also manually release them later, which may be more effort than necessary for this specific task.)*

Please let me know if you require any extra clarification. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!